# How to set intervals in cron jobs?

Tags: plugins, cron, wp-cron, ssh

I am having a unmanaged VPS, where my wordpress site is hosted, I am also using WP-ROBOT 3 plugin for auto posting, I want it to do auto post through cron jobs, 
According to the documentation of the plugin, I entered this code through SSH command 
`wget --post-data='mincamp=2&maxcamp=3&chance=50' -O /dev/null http://myURL/` and it worked, but I want to set regular intervals, so that it autoposts everyday, how to do that?
I want it to post after every 6 hours, what should be the cron commands

Comment: Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via wp_cron by using the following,

```
function more_reccurences() {
return array(
    'sixhourly' => array('interval' => 21600, 'display' => 'Every 6 hours'),
);
}
add_filter('cron_schedules', 'more_reccurences');
```

then find the function that does the autopost and call it by

```
if ( !wp_next_scheduled('autopost_function') ) {
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'sixhourly', 'autopost_function');
}
```

If you want to use linux cron should be something like: * 6,12,18,24 * * * /some-command

**-new edit: 28-3-2011**

I think things are getting mixed up here, let me clarify.
This * 6,12,18,24 * * * /some-command goes into your crontab file, which is completely outside  your webserver and wordpress. This **cannot** be used in php.

If you want to schedule it in wordpress you will need the functions that I gave. I'm not very familiar with wp-robot but i can give try to help. wp-robot is premium so I cant check the code.

the code I gave at the top executes the autopost function every six hours. You need to write the autopost_function yourself or find a function in wp-robot you can trigger.

ill give some examples:

*example ssh command:*

```
function autopost_function() {
$cmd = escapeshellcmd('wget --post-data='mincamp=2&maxcamp=3&chance=50' -O /dev/null http://myURL/');
  exec ($cmd);
}
```

Please note that using exec() is considered **very dangerous** in PHP, if not done correctly your entire server can be compromised/hacked and it may not run correctly if your server is running in safe-mode. You could try opening the page with curl which would better but your server would need curl support.

Instead of the above I would use the following function to add posts programmatically. But this has nothing to do with wp-robot.

*example wp function:*

```
    function autopost_function() {
// Create post object
  $my_post = array(
     'post_title' => 'My post',
     'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_author' => 1,
     'post_category' => array(8,39)
  );

// Insert the post into the database
  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
```

this function simply adds a post to the database, you can pass a lot of parameters to it. Look up wp_insert_post() on the codex for more information. Doing it like this is **much safer**, and easier.

You can use the above code outside wp-robot, so you wont have to change the core files. All examples I have written are untested so they might contain some syntax problems.
Hope this helps get you going.

Comment: @Patriek I want to use Linux Cron, I mean to say that anyhow I want to start the auto posting, the php function which you provided, if I enter that, then will the auto posting start?

Comment: for the linux cron its * 6,12,18,24 * * * /your-command, you should put this in your cron schedule files. read more here http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference. The php functions are for wordpress cron, which is complete different you can ignore that if you want to use linux cron

Comment: @Patriek where to write the function in wp-cron file? I mean before `die();` or after that?

and where to write if condition which you mentioned? after this function?

Comment: @Patriek hey this is OK, I want to adopt the wp-cron.php file method for setting the cron intervals, my question is the `function more_reccurences() {` and the if condition `if ( !wp_next_scheduled('autopost_function') ) {` where this code has to be entered in wp-cron.php file?

Comment: Dont alter the wp-cron file, best way to include is to write a simple one page plugin. It might work from your theme's functions.php but not sure if that works you can try it.

Comment: so it means that, I have to just copy paste those functions in function.php file?

Comment: yes see if that works.

Comment: ok I ll check and let you know :)

Comment: @Patriek through linux when we type `* */6 * * * command` what will be the command for wp-robot plugin?

Comment: * 6,12,18,24 * * * wget --post-data='mincamp=2&maxcamp=3&chance=50' -O /dev/null http://myURL/ but this has to be entered in the crontab, you cant execute this manually. The cron deamon reads this and executes the command entered after the schedule.